# Modal Pop up when if statement hit PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'm unable to call my modal in this PHP file to be called when and if statement is valued to be true

Modal

```
 <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

PHP code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <?php
            // trying to target modal

            if (true){

                // not able to call

                  echo "$( document ).ready(function(){ $('#form').modal('show')";

              

            }

            else{



                echo "alert(\"haha\")";

        }
   

?>
```

Please help thank you, so it should open a pop up when the if statement is true but it is not working.

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't look like you have `<script>` tags

Comment: Where's your element with the ID of form wrt `$('#form')`? What errors do you get in your console?

Comment: Look at the code generated by your PHP script. Press Ctrl+U in your browser and it will become clear why this doesn't work.

Comment: 1) the code is being output as text, not in a `<script>` tag; 2) the `(` after `ready` and the `{` after `function()` are never closed; and 3) `$('#form')` is looking for something with `id="form"`, but what you show has `id="myModal"`

Comment: Try testing the jquery code in isolation first... also try looking in your browser's Console for errors... if the best you can tell is that it's "not working" then that indicates that you have not done any of the basic investigation or testing which should be a minimum requirement when looking at such problems. If you don't know how to use the tools built into your browser to debug javascript/jquery code, now would be a great time to go and learn...otherwise you'll never be able to fix even simple issues with your programs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will just need to change a couple of items to get your popup to work. First don't forget your closing braces in your script tags and second, be sure to use the same ID so that it knows what one to look for.

```
//Your ID should match the ID of the modal you would like to open
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in your script, be sure to add the same ID from the myModal DIV

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <?php
        // trying to target modal
        if (true){
            // not able to call
            echo "
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                $(document).ready(function(){ 
                    $('#myModal').modal('show'); //myModal is ID of div
                });    //Don't forget your closing braces
            </script>           
            ";
        }
        else{
            echo "alert(\"haha\")";
        } 
    ?>
```

Comment: does not work :( have you tried this on a code pen?
Thank so much!!

Comment: @chasd I ran it on my local machine. Works for me

Comment: it worked now because I did not have bootstrap added to html

Answer (score 0):

we can write php code anywhere on the page so try to write php condition inside javascript like this way

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
            <?php
            if (true){
             ?>

                 $( document ).ready(function(){ $('#form').modal('show')});

              <?php 
              }
           else{
             ?>
                   alert("haha");
           <?php
               }
              ?>
</script>
```

Comment: it does not work as well :(

Comment: I don't have enough rep to vote your answer sorry!